# Check if int is nil in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I know in C int cannot be nil, which brings me to ask this question. I am using a rails API that uses an int for a certain property (rating). This API call could return nothing for the rating because it doesn't have a rating yet.  I am using RestKit to map the results of the API call.

Maybe I should convert the int passed back from server API call to an NSNumber instead of an int? Or can I check in int is nil some how?

Comment: You tagged "Objective-C" and you say you use Rails. Am I missing something? Also, I believe Obj-C is defined as a "strict superset of C".

Comment: `int` cannot be `nil` in Obj-C. Only object types (pointer) can be `nil` (`null`). If you want to have a way to handle `nil`, you need to use objects (e.g. `NSNumber`). This is what most parsing frameworks do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `NSNumber`, which is an object and can therefore be `nil`.  It can wrap integers, floating points and booleans:

```
NSNumber *number = nil;
if (!number) {
    NSLog(@"Number not assigned");
}

number = @1;
if (number) {
    NSLog(@"Number assigned: %d", [number intValue]);
}
```